# Force "Add to homescreen" prompt a second time on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a PWA. I managed to trigger the prompt a first time and installed the app on my shell (desktop). I then deleted it and I would like to force the prompt to reappear (for debug purpose) but it won't.

I set my chome flag `Bypass user engagement checks` to `enabled`, but there's still nothing I can do to trigger the prompt.

When I click on the console setting `Application>Manifest>Add to homescreen`, nothing happens and I don't receive any error message either.

It's exactly the same code that worked the first time. I just want to trigger it again now that the desktop shortcut has been deleted.

Comment: You can always trigger the Add to Homescreen manually as stated in [PWA FAQS](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen#what_are_the_requirements_for_a_site_to_use_improved_add_to_home_screen): "Users will continue to get the existing add to home screen experience, though if they add it again manually via the menu button, the new icon will use improved add to home screen."
Additional notes, [Add to Homescreen](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also struggled with this issue.
At last found that going to [chrome://apps/](http://chrome://apps/) and removing the app will enable to re-add it

Answer (score 0):

If the  `chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks` flag is enabled and you are still not getting the banner, its high likely one of [PWA criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) is not met anymore. 
It might have worked before. But with the changing code, something might have went wrong with Service worker, accessing via HTTP instead of HTTPS or having an invalid certificate kind if issues might have made your app not eligible for App install banner.

Validate:  Validate your current sites PWA eligibility using Chrome Developer tools ->  Audits -> Perform Audit -> Progressive Web App. See if all goes through regarding PWA criteria and if you see all looks good and still you don't get the Install Banner, post the Audit screenshot to give us some idea on whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can just also just set it in the Developer Tools under Application by checking on Update on reload or click on Unregister to completely remove the SW.  Dirty, but does the trick all the time.

[image]